# How to Get data from child pages in cq5?

Tags: java, jsp, aem

I have to create a parent page which will be overview page. It will have 5 child pages which are detail pages and will contain title and text. I want that my parent page should fetch the title and text from these 5 child pages and display on overview. There will also be a link on parent page which will take it to respective child page. Please help with the implementation.

Comment: Have you tried : https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/javadoc/com/day/cq/wcm/api/Page.html#listChildren()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fetching data from child pages in cq5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34960284/fetching-data-from-child-pages-in-cq5)

Comment: AEM List component (/libs/wcm/foundation/components/list) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You may use [Page interface:](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/diff-previous/changes/com.day.cq.wcm.api.Page.html)

```
Iterator<Page> iterator = currentPage.listChildren();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Page childPage = iterator.next();
    ValueMap childProps = childPage.getProperties();
    String title = childProps.get("title", "");
    String text = childProps.get("text", "");
    //output this props values just like you want to
}
```